# Accessing Github packages with Fine-grained personal access tokens

Tags: github, github-packages, github-fine-grained-tokens

Our organization recently switched to **Fine-grained personal access tokens(Beta)** but we saw a limitation there regarding the read/write of the Github packages.

As per GitHub documentation, it's possible only with classic tokens. I am referring to doc - [Github Doc](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-apache-maven-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages)

[image]

Is there any workaround to **use the GitHub packages** with **Fine-grained tokens** as we don't want to use the classic token?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not supported yet, check:

https://github.com/github/roadmap/issues/558

Comment: If the documentation says it is only possible with classic token, then it's only possible with classic tokens. Do you think they would write that if it somehow was possible with fine grained tokens?