# Publish a nuget in Github Packages using an Application Installation Token

Tags: nuget, github-actions, dotnet-publish, github-packages

I am trying to publish a Nuget package for an organization in Github using dotnet publish.

We are planning publish packages from a Github actions from a repository in one organisation to the packages feed that's hosted in another organisation. As such we can't rely on the `GITHUB_TOKEN` that's assigned to the workflow.

It works fine when I use a personal access token with permissions to write artifacts in that organization. We don't really want to use a personal token tied to a user.

We thought using a Github App could be a good option. I was able to get an access token from the Github App installation, which was configured with permissions to read/write artifacts.

That token works fine for making calls to the packages API, I can retrieve or do write operations with existing packages.

However, it does not work when it is used with dotnet publish (as `--api-key` parameter). It can not be a problem with permissions as the calls to the package API are working fine.

Does anyone know if that scenario is supported ?

Comment: You'll have to define "supported". :D. Can you share a piece of your workflow that fetches the keys and that sets up the nugget account secrets?

Comment: Are you refreshing the app token? They have a limited lifetime.  Did you add this action to grab a new token for the workflow? https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-app-token

Answer (score 4):

### GitHub App Token

If you are using a GitHub App with the right permissions to write to the feed, you'll need to fetch an app token in your workflow and use that instead of the `GITHUB_TOKEN` secret.

```
steps:
 - id: create_token
   uses: tibdex/github-app-token@v2
   with:
     app_id: ${{ secrets.APP_ID }}
     private_key: ${{ secrets.PRIVATE_KEY }}


 - run: "echo 'The created token is masked: ${{ steps.create_token.outputs.token }}'"
```

> Note: [Check the docs for the action to further limit the permissions and repositories the token is minted for](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-app-token).

You can then use that token to authenticate against GitHub packages similar to now you'd do it in a normal workflow.

```
- pwsh: |
    dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password $env:TOKEN --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/NAMESPACE/index.json"
  env:
    TOKEN: ${{ steps.create_token.outputs.token }}
```

### The following applies if you are publishing within the same organisation.

GitHub Actions can be granted the `packages: write` permission with that it can publish new packages with the `GITHUB_TOKEN` variable.

For existing packages you can go to the details page of the package, package settings and then grant GitHub actions access to that package.

[image]

Be sure to [authenticate to the feed as described in the docs](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-in-a-github-actions-workflow).

Use the following command to authenticate to GitHub Packages in a GitHub Actions workflow using the GITHUB_TOKEN instead of hardcoding a personal access token in a nuget.config file in the repository:

```
dotnet nuget add source --username USERNAME --password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/NAMESPACE/index.json"
```

Replace NAMESPACE with the name of the personal account or organization to which your packages are scoped.

The actual username doesn't matter.

Comment: I forgot to mention we need to support an scenario for publishing nuget packages across organizations. The solution you gave with GITHUB_TOKEN works fine as long as we are executing the action in the same org, but it's not possible to push a package to another org. That's why we want to use a github app with permissions at org level

Comment: Ahh important additional information!

Comment: @PabloCibraro updated 

Comment: So I am creating a token as it is documented here https://docs.github.com/en/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/generating-a-user-access-token-for-a-github-app. I configured the app with packages:write on that org and wrote a custom action to get the token. The token has the packages:write permissions. The dotnet publish still returns 403 with that token

Comment: I will try the custom action you shared. Thanks

Comment: It says "for existing packages" but I am unable to create new packages with an action. The only way I can get it to go is to manually upload the package, then link it to the repository with write permissions on actions. Otherwise the write action fails due to a lack of permissions. This might be due to new hardening or my settings.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a GitHub App token cannot be used to authenticate to packages to push/restore packages. "GitHub Packages only supports authentication using a personal access token (classic). For more information, see "Managing your personal access tokens." https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages

There is the aforementioned beta to allow the GitHub Workflow token to be able to access packages, ie from another repository.

Comment: @JoshJohanning you are correct: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76820822/736079